# Hamiltonian path in bike-lock graph with $1$ known digit

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, hamiltonian-graphs, hamiltonian-paths

**Motivation.** My youngest son has a bike lock with dials, and he forgot the unlocking combination completely, *except* that he remembered that digit $0$ appeared somewhere in the combination. So it was my task to go through all the zillions (but, fortunately, finitely many) possible combinations. Which led to the following problem.

**Formal statement.** Let $n \geq 2$ be an integer, so we have $n = \{0, \ldots, n-1\}$. For any integer $k>1$ let $$V^0_k = \{x \in n^k: (\exists j\in k)x(j) = 0\}, $$ and let two distinct elements $a\neq b \in V^0_k$ form an edge iff there is $j\in k$ such that

1. $a(i) = b(i)$ for all $i\in n\setminus\{j\}$, and
2. $\{a(j), b(j)\} = \{x, x+1\}$ for some $x\in n-1$, or $\{a(j), b(j)\} = \{0, n-1\}$.

Denote the set of edges by $E_k$.

For what positive integers $k, n$ does the graph $(V^0_k, E_k)$ have a Hamiltonian path? And, if there is a Hamiltonian path, can also a Hamiltonian cycle be found? (The second question doesn't need to be answered for acceptance.)

Comment: Do you want a Hamiltonian cycle (as suggested in the title) or a Hamiltonian path (as suggested in the question)?

Comment: Good point @DustinG.Mixon -> I would already be happy with a path, but a cycle would even be nicer. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: The bike lock task seems to motivate the path version (why would one need to return to the first combination?), but the cycle version is probably harder.

Comment: That's right @JukkaKohonen, I modified the question accordingly and was just wondering about cycles additionally. But the path question is closest to my heart, so to say.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen: to double check (I guess you could go back, but that's cheating)

Comment: I think kabenyuk's answer deserves being the "accepted" one, because it was first and addressed the primary (path) part of the question...

Comment: Ok thanks for your fairness @JukkaKohonen -- I would have liked to accept both answers, as you added valuable insights. I changed acceptance back to the way you suggested.

Comment: Thanks :) Perhaps we will yet see the ultimate answer that addresses all $k$ and $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $k=2$, then a Hamiltonian path is constructed easily.
In the case $k=3$ and $n\equiv1\pmod2$ a Hamiltonian path is constructed as follows:
\begin{align*}\label{cycle}
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% x=0
   & x_1=0\\
   &(0,n-1,n-1)-(0,n-2,n-1)-\ldots-(0,0,n-1)-\\ % z=n-1
  -&(0,0,n-2)-(0,1,n-2)-\ldots-(0,n-1,n-2)-\\  % z=n-2
  -&(0,n-1,n-3)-(0,n-2,n-3)-\ldots-(0,n-1,n-3)-\\  % z=n-3
   &\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\\
  -&(0,0,1)-(0,1,1)-\ldots-(0,n-1,1)-\\ % z=1
  -&(0,n-1,0)-(0,n-2,0)-\ldots-(0,0,0)-\\ % z=0
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% z=0,x\neq0
   \\
   & x_3=0,\,x_1\neq0\\
  -&(1,0,0)-(1,1,0)-\ldots-(1,n-1,0)-\\ % x=1
  -&(2,n-1,0)-(2,n-2,0)-\ldots-(2,0,0)-\\ % x=2
   &\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\\
  -&(n-2,0,0)-(n-2,1,0)-\ldots-(n-2,n-1,0)-\\ % x=n-2
  -&(n-1,n-1,0)-(n-1,n-2,0)-\ldots-(n-1,0,0)-\\ % x=n-1
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% y=0
   \\
   & x_2=0,x_1\neq0,x_3\neq0\\
  -&(n-1,0,1)-(n-1,0,2)-\ldots-(n-1,0,n-1)-\\ % x=n-1
  -&(n-2,0,n-1)-(n-2,0,n-2)-\ldots-(n-2,0,1)-\\ % x=n-2
   &\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\\
  -&(2,0,n-1)-(2,0,n-2)-\ldots-(2,0,1)-\\ % x=2
  -&(1,0,1)-(1,0,2)-\ldots-(1,0,n-1). % x=1
\end{align*}
In this table, the points are written out in the order they are traversed. The little comments make the table easier to read (I think so).
If $n\equiv0\pmod2$, then the Hamiltonian path is constructed similarly.
It seems to me that in the case $k>3$ the Hamiltonian path can also be constructed in a similar way.

**Edit.**

I tried to make the above Hamiltonian path more visual. The picture shows all vertices of the two graphs at $n=9$ and $n=10$ and almost all edges. Only edges of type $(0,i,j)-(n-1,i,j)$ are not shown. We see that the Hamiltonian path exists without these edges.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer to the cycle version.

**Case $k=2$, any $n$:** The graph has no Hamiltonian cycle. If $n \ge 3$, the graph consists of two $n$-cycles that intersect at a single point $(0,0)$. If $n=2$, the graph is just the chain $(0,1),(0,0),(1,0)$.

---

**Case $k \ge 3$ and $n$ even:** The graph has no Hamiltonian cycle. This is because the graph is bipartite and $|V|$ is odd, and you cannot have an odd-length cycle with two alternating colors.

- To see that it is bipartite, color each vertex blue if the sum of
  coordinates is even, and red if the sum of coordinates is odd; every
  edge in the graph moves just one coordinate, either between $i$ and
  $i+1$ (different parities), or between $n-1$ (odd) and $0$ (even), so
  it flips the color.
- To see that $|V|$ is odd, note that $V = A
     \setminus B$, where $A = \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}^k$, that is all $k$-digit
  strings, and $B = \{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}^k$, that is all $k$-digit strings
  without zeros. Clearly $|V|=|A|-|B|$, with $|A|$ even and $|B|$
  odd, so $|V|$ is odd.

---

**Case $k \ge 3$ and $n$ odd:** Computations suggest that there *is* a Hamiltonian cycle, but this is inconclusive. I have verified by straightforward [SageMath code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=gedgtw) with $k=3$ up to $n=11$, and with $(k,n) \in \{(4,3),(4,5),(5,3)\}$.

Now the bipartity argument does not apply, because $0$ and $n-1$ have same parity, so the wraparound edges make the graph non-bipartite. (The wraparound possibility is essential; if we leave out the wraparound edges, there is again no Hamiltonian cycle, because the graph is again bipartite and has odd number of vertices.)

Here is an example solution with $k=3$, $n=5$. Green lines indicate wraparound between $0$ and $4$. I don't see any glaring structure in the machine-generated solution, so it is difficult to generalize from that.

```
000-040-140-240-340-300-310-410-420-320-
220-210-110-100-104-103-003-403-404-304-
303-302-301-201-200-204-203-202-102-101-
001-041-031-030-020-120-130-230-330-430-
440-400-401-402-002-012-013-023-033-043-
042-032-022-021-011-010-014-024-034-044-
004
```

[image: Bike lock solution with k=3, n=5]

**Update.** Here is a manually designed solution for $k=3$, $n=7$. From the picture it is probably clear how it generalizes to any odd $n$. Interestingly, we only need to do one wraparound.

[image: Bike lock solution with k=3, n=7]

Comment: The last figure is very clear!